# Postgres Docker Container tables not present in local DB windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, containers

From windows, I connected to Postgres Docker container from the local machine. But I can't see the tables that are existed in postgres container. The data is not replicating locally. I followed this [tutorial](https://kingsor.github.io/2019/03/23/using-postgres-with-docker-on-windows/) 
for running the postgres container on windows.

I managed to create the tables from dump file.

```
$ docker volume create --name postgres-volume

$ docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres_db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -v postgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres

$ docker exec -it <container-id> bash -c "pg_dump -h <source-url> -U postgres  -d postgres > /tmp/dump.sql"

$ docker exec -it <container-id> bash -c "psql -f /tmp/dump.sql -U postgres -d postgres"
```

Any help, appreciated.

Comment: When you mount the same docker volume to the PostgreSQL's data path, the tables are gone after a container restart?

Comment: The tables were not present before either. Should I map local DB to any path.?

Comment: By "Docker Postgres table" do you mean the default system catalogues that exist by default in database?

Comment: @AliTou No!! My custom tables which I have created.

Comment: Does your container have any file in `/tmp/dump.sql`? The root of filesystem of your containers are empty by default, and you must either mount a volume (as @edd said in his answer), or populate it in its Dockerfile when building. As in your steps doesn't show anything that you're doing so, I think the above command will not create any table, because there was no `/tmp/dump.sql` there.

Comment: Updated the question. I am actually fetching dump from the Url. and using them to create the schema

Comment: @RahulReddy Make sure you're dumping the DB you want (pg_dump only dumps the one you select, `-d`, not all). Make sure you're getting what you planned for in the dump. Output the dump to your host (`docker exec ... bash -c "pg_dump ..." > /path/in/local/host`) and inspect it in your host. If you can't redirect (not familiar with windows), mount the dump output directory to a host path and inspect it there. You can see more details in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Containers

Containers are meant to be an isolated instance of a program/service. They are isolated both from the host and subsequent spawns of the same image. They start off in an isolated island, with nothing in it (that it didn't bring itself). Any data they generate is lost upon their death. They are, also, completely oblivious to any data on the host (for now). But, sometimes, we want their data to be persistent or "inject" our own data each time they start up. Such as your case with `PostgreSQL`. We want `PostgreSQL` to have our schema available each time it starts up. And, it would also be great if it retained any changes we made or data we loaded.

## Docker Volumes

Enter [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). It is a good method to manage persistent storage for containers. They are meant to be mounted in containers and let them write their data (or read from prior instances) which will not be deleted if the container instance is deleted. Once you create a volume with `docker volume create myvolume1`, it'll create a directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` (on windows it'll be another default. Can be changed). You never have to be aware of the physical directory on your host. You only need be aware of the volume name `myvolume1` (or whatever name you choose it to have).

## Containers with persistent data (docker volumes)

As we said, containers, by default, are completely isolated from the host. Specifically its filesystem, too. Which means, when a container starts up, it doesn't know what's on the host's filesystem. And, when the container instance is deleted, the data it generated during its life perishes with it.
But, that'll be different if we use `docker volumes`. Upon a container's start-up, we can mount within it data from "outside". This data can either be the `docker volume` we spoke of earlier or a specific path we want (such as /home/me/somethingimport which we manage ourselves). The latter isn't a `docker volume` but works just the same.

## [Tutorial](https://kingsor.github.io/2019/03/23/using-postgres-with-docker-on-windows/)

The tutorial you linked talks about mounting both a path and a `docker volume` (in separate examples). This is done with the `-v` flag when you execute `docker run`. Because using `docker` on windows, there is an issue with permissions to the `PostgreSQL` data directory on the host (which is mounted in the container), they recommend using `docker volumes`.
This means you'll have to create your schema and load any data you need after you used a `docker volume` with your instance of `PostgreSQL`. Subsequent restarts of the container must use the same `docker volume`.

```sh
docker volume create --name postgres-volume

docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres_db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -v postgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

> From the tutorial

These are the two important lines. The first creates creates a `docker volume` and the second starts a *fresh* `PostgreSQL` instance. Any changes you make to that instance's data (DML DDL), will be saved in the `docker volume` *postgres-volume*. If you've previously spun up a container (for example, `PostgreSQL`) that uses that volume, it'll find the data just as it was left last time. In other words, what makes the second line a *fresh* instance is the fact that the `docker volume` is empty (it was just created). Subsequent instances of `PostgreSQL` will find the schema+data you loaded previously.

Comment: Thats a very clear info, But Everything is going well, except that from windows, after the connection to the database locally from my system, the `schema` for the specified DB is empty. Container unable to pass the schema information (tables) to my machine

Comment: @RahulReddy Did you pass the volume for `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`? This is the directory that your db check to initially create your schemas, etc.

Comment: @AliTou !! I will check it

Comment: @RahulReddy How did you created your tables? You `exec`ed inside postgres, got a psql shell, and created tables? The tutorial doesn't have any parts about creating schemas. Please also add your attempt to create tables in your question.